# aspnet c# form submision using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a aspnet web application which is hosted on my local iis. In other web application I want a link and when I click on the link, it's should open my hosted web application without asking credentials. I am using below code to do that but it's not working.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenURL() {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
        form.setAttribute("action", "http://10.10.10.10/Domain/Login.aspx");

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "UserName");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "UserTest"); 
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "Password");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("value", "PasswordTest");
        form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
    </script>
<body onload="OpenURL();">
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting actual html tags in your  then onLoad you simply submit the form, like this:
(pseudo-code just to give a hint, can't test it atm)

```
<body onLoad="javascript:myform.submit();">
  <form name="myform"...>
  <input ...>
  <input ..>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Now I'm using below code as per your suggestion but still not working. FYI- In my target web application, I've used login control. <html> <body onload="javascript:form.submit();"> <form name="form" action="10.10.10.10/Domain/Login.aspx">; <input type="hidden" id="UserName" value="UserTest" /> <input type="hidden" id="Password" value="PasswordTest" /> </form> </body> </html>

Answer (score 0):

try this for all input elements:

```
hiddenField.type = "hidden";
hiddenField.name = "UserName";
hiddenField.value = "UserTest";
```

instead of:

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "UserName");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "UserTest");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best if you set the proper endpoint on your hosted web application, rather than just passing/assigning the credentials directly using javascript.

You can create a controller method that mimics the function of the login submit, passing the encrypted information and decoding it on your hosted web application, and setting the landing page after you have processed the encrypted credentials. Something like,

```
http://10.10.10.10/Domain/LoginRedirect?data=your_encrypted_data_here
```

But if what you are trying to do is to fetch/save/update some information on your hosted web app, you can try creating an api endpoint, and authenticate/perform using restful calls.